# Rails: How do I find out what fields are in an active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got an active record class open. 
I want to know all the fields available to me in that class?
How can I do this quickly, without walking over to the database design document hanging on my wall?

I'm trying to wrap my head around having public data elements, obfuscated from me, but I just find it so frustrating to get at the field names available.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Model.attribute_names` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I was more thinking, while looking at the code, not at run time. I've basically got a class with public members/variables.  I'm reading the code, and I've no clue what they are.

Comment: The database schema `db/schema.rb` could give you a hint. Or you may analyze the migration files in `db/migrate/`. But this may be a lot of work depending on how often the schema changed.

Answer (score 1):

The [annotate](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) gem is great for this.